# Running each row of a CSV with a module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, subprocess, data-processing

Working in Python 3.8.5

Problem: CSV file containing 100 rows, two columns containing data that are needed for a module to perform a calculation. I would like to run each row with the two data points, take the output and insert it into a third column.

Action so far: I found the module CSV and can use CSV.reader to read each line. I can see how I would get the output of the data points but not how to take them and use them in the module I need to run to process the data. I also found subprocess which I believe is the module which will let me process each line. I'm just finding it difficult to connect both of these.

Example data:

```
DateTime,Date,Time,Wind_Direction,Effective_Fetch,Wind_Speed
01/10/2012 00:00,01/10/2012,00:00:00,228,510,1.976
01/10/2012 00:10,01/10/2012,00:10:00,231,516,1.389
01/10/2012 00:20,01/10/2012,00:20:00,239,532,1.759
```

The two columns I want to process are `Effective_Fetch` and `Wind_Speed`.

The module is as follows:

```
def Hs(w, Lf):
    gravity=9.81 #ms^-2
    slope=0.0026
    x = (slope)*(gravity**(-0.53))*(w**(1.06)*(Lf**(0.47)))
    return x
```

`w` is `Wind_Speed`, `Lf` is `Effective_Fetch` and `x` is the value that I would like to insert into a column following `Wind_Speed` with the column header "Wave_Height" - I've read other modules that should be able to do this too in Pandas.

Comment: `subprocess` seems to be a red herring, you don't need it to process lines in a CSV file but for starting subprocesses (= other programs).

Comment: Ah OK, so I'm down the wrong track there. Any suggestions on the best way forward for this please? I'm wondering if I just write another module that just extracts the data into a new list but I still can't work out how to draw out each datapoint and use it (I have script to do this in R, not Python but it has to be python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```py
output_rows = []
with open('mycsv.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip the first (header) row
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        # Unpack the two values we are interested in, ignore the others
        *_, effective_fetch, wind_speed = row
        # Values read from CSVs are strings, so cast them to numeric types
        result = Hs(float(wind_speed), int(effective_fetch))
        # Make a new row of the original row and the result of calling Hs
        output_rows.append(row + [result])

# Write out a new csv (if required)
with open('mynewcsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_f:
    writer = csv.writer(new_f)
    writer.writerow(headers + ['wave_height'])
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

The `csv.reader` object is an iterator, so using the `next` function advances it one step.  This is less awkward than having a condition within the main for loop to check if we are processing the first row.

The `Hs` function requires two inputs, and luckily they are the final two columns in the csv rows.

```
*_, effective_fetch, wind_speed = row
```

tells the interpreter to assign the values of the last two columns to `effective_fetch` and `wind_speed`, and assign all the previous columns to a variable named `_`, which is a common naming convention for a variable that we intend to ignore (you can call it whatever you like, of course).

You could also do this by row index, especially if the columns were less conveniently placed:

```
 effective_fetch, wind_speed = row[4], row[5]
```

or by indexing from the end:

```
 effective_fetch, wind_speed = row[-2], row[-1]
```

or by list slicing:

```
 effective_fetch, wind_speed = row[4:]
 effective_fetch, wind_speed = row[-2:]
```

Comment: You are so brilliant thank you. Thinking about this last night I was going down this track a bit in my head but it's just such a relief to have something that looks like it'll work.  Thanks for introducing me to "next", handy for skipping headers indeed. Also my first intro to "with" - think I'll add that into my teaching for future too as it's useful.

Comment: I've had a go. Most of it is working. I'm stuck again though. I can generate the new calculated data fine thanks to your script. However if I print (result) it just shows the last value in the list, not all of the values. This is causing issues as I can't seem to append all the values in a new column. I've been following instructions from here: https://thispointer.com/python-add-a-column-to-an-existing-csv-file/

Comment: The last line of the code <<output_rows.append(row + [result])>> was bringing an error (output_rows is undefined). If I replace it with print(result) then I can see all the data generated so I know the <<result = Hs(float(wind_speed), int(effective_fetch))>> line is working fine. I tried defining output_rows as the original CSV file, I've tried lots of things actually... @snakecharmerb

Comment: Oops, sorry about the missing `output_rows` - it should be a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) - I've added it to the code in the answer.

Comment: No problem...it was such a simple bit to be missing. Even my husband said that I needed to create an array (or empty list) but I  didn't realise I needed to put it before the code and I was thinking way too hard *sigh* thank you again. I'm heavily pregnant so my brain is also pretty rubbish at the moment :( roll on maternity leave @snakecharmerb